# Configuring a meta query with multiple post types that have the same relationship on a single page

Tags: custom-post-types, php, wp-query, functions, meta-query

I am creating a client portal were my clients can maintain their projects and leave feedback. I have two custom post types called "Clients" and "Projects" and they each pull information from one another in the backend. When I create a client it automatically generates its postID to a drop down menu on the projects post type were I can assign a client to a project.

What I am trying to accomplish is by displaying all projects that are associated with the selected client on a single page on the front end. The single page will be the client portal, which is generated by the client post type.

I seem to be having trouble with the value and the compare. When I change the value to the clients actually ID number I get all the assign projects for client A, but when viewing client B I am viewing client A projects ( I know this because I am assigning the value to a specific client ID). Now when I change the value to `get_the_ID()` it does not display any of the post unless I change the compare to NOT IN. Is there a way I can display all selected project post to its assign client without displaying all post I have created in the custom project post?

Here is my code for single.php which will be displaying the projects on the clients portal.

```
 <?php 
 global $post; 
$projects = new WP_Query( array( 
'post_type'         => array( 'projects'), 
'posts_per_page'    => -1,
'post_status'     => 'publish',
    'meta_query'        => array( 
        array( 
            'key'           => 'clientType', 
            'value'         => array( $postid = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'clientType', true )),   
            'compare'       => 'LIKE', 
            'type'          => 'NUMERIC' 
)))); 
 ?>
```

Below is the code I am using to assign a client to a projects in the admin panel of projects. This script displays any client that I created in the client page and display their names in a drop down menu.

```
 class projects {
   var $FOR_POST_TYPE = 'projects';
   var $SELECT_POST_TYPE = 'client_portal';
   var $SELECT_POST_LABEL = 'Client';
   var $box_id;
   var $box_label;
   var $field_id;
   var $field_label;
   var $field_name;
   var $meta_key;
    function __construct() {
      add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'admin_init' ) );
    }
 function admin_init() {
     add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'add_meta_boxes' ) );
     add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_post' ), 10, 2 );
    $this->meta_key     = "_selected_{$this->SELECT_POST_TYPE}";
    $this->box_id       = "select-{$this->SELECT_POST_TYPE}-metabox";
    $this->field_id     = "selected-{$this->SELECT_POST_TYPE}";
    $this->field_name   = "selected_{$this->SELECT_POST_TYPE}";
    $this->box_label    = __( "Select {$this->SELECT_POST_LABEL}", 'projects'         );
    $this->field_label  = __( "Choose {$this->SELECT_POST_LABEL}", 'projects'    );
   }
 function add_meta_boxes() {
  add_meta_box(
       $this->box_id,
       $this->box_label,
       array( $this, 'select_box' ),
       $this->FOR_POST_TYPE,
       'side'
    );
 }
   function select_box( $post ) {
     $selected_post_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'clientType', true );
     global $wp_post_types;
     $save_hierarchical = $wp_post_types[$this->SELECT_POST_TYPE]->hierarchical;
     $wp_post_types[$this->SELECT_POST_TYPE]->hierarchical = true;
     wp_dropdown_pages( array(
      'id' => $this->field_id,
      'name' => $this->field_name,
     'selected' => empty( $selected_post_id ) ? 0 : $selected_post_id,
     'post_type' => $this->SELECT_POST_TYPE,
     'show_option_none' => $this->field_label,
          ));
     $wp_post_types[$this->SELECT_POST_TYPE]->hierarchical = $save_hierarchical;
          }
     function save_post( $post_id, $post ) {
        if ( $post->post_type == $this->FOR_POST_TYPE && isset( $_POST[$this->field_name] ) ) {
      update_post_meta( $post_id, 'clientType', $_POST[$this->field_name] );
       }
     }
   }
 new projects();
```

Comment: if the meta field contains a single numeric ID, why are you wrapping the ID in quotes and using a `LIKE` query, and not simply `=`?

Comment: i thought that as well. So the file I am working on, I changed the value to    value => array( $postid = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'clientType', true )), then LIKE to = and I have not ben able to display anything @Milo

Comment: When I run a echo print it keeps repeating the same oldest Client ID (91) instead of switching the ID to the selective client, example ID 188 @Milo